# What to do if model is black in cycles render engine?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

Here's a screenshot of what the model looks like

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2xb2.png]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please pack the image you are using? File > External Data > Pack Resources, then save and share again

Answer (score 1):

The reason it appears black is that the normals of your model are flipped.

I turned on face orientation in the viewport (There is a checkbox in the overlays panel). Blue means you are looking at the front side of the face and red means you are looking at the back side of the face.
[image]

To solve this, go to edit mode. Select the red faces, click alt+n and select flip. Do This for all the objects.

Comment: it didn't help, but maybe the problem is that the model is emitting a shadow but there is no change on the model from the light source.

Comment: It did work for me though. But I forgot to mention one thing. Some of the UV maps are absolutely messed up. Please check those as well. If there is anything else I will add it to the answer. Also the texture was not available in the blend file that you provided(Plz pack and reupload as said by moonboots in the comments on your question). So I had tested it with a UV color grid.

Comment: @Qiwi checked the model once again. There are a few places where there is double geometry.  That is messing up our geometry even more.

Comment: @Qiwi ttps://imgur.com/a/UgQbttx I corrected some UVs and cleaned up some of the geometry. It's a total mess. Basically on further inspection your model has multiple issues. Please solve these and tell us if your issues are solved

Comment: The file starts to weigh 32 megabytes, so I can't share it via Blend-Exchange.
And what I need to fix and how I need to fix it?
And it's not my model.

Comment: @Qiwi It's just a lot of manual cleanup. Find out all the places where there is duplicate geometry. Delete any of the excess stuff. And also scale and position the uv maps. If possible, after deleting the excess geo, just unwrap it again and reposition it. If you don't know how to do all this stuff, well, I don't want to sound unhelpful, but learn all this stuff. These are kind of basics.

Comment: i cleaned it up and shared the file

Comment: @Qiwi https://imgur.com/a/B0nVod1 This is a screenshot of your arm. This is the duplicate geometry I am talking about. Delete tha outer stuff(Works for a few parts, idk obout others). Another thing, remove all the junk geometry near the head. Also in the fourth image, you can see that some of the UVs are just scaled to like 0.001 compared to their size. This is the case for many of them. As I said there's a lot of manual cleanup. At this point it's not one single issue. It's just a really bad model. So since there are so many problems I don't think that this can have a single answer

Comment: @Qiwi as Akshay2005 says, there is a double layer of geometry, the outer geometry is just laying over pure black, it was probably used to create an outline, you need to select this outer geometry with L and remove it with X, then it will work correctly (also recalculate the normals as Akshay2005 says)